# Alternative for <input type = time>?

Tags: html

I was in need of an input of type time where users need to enter  'from' and 'to' times and I   found this

`<input type="time">`

but it won't work in firefox , ie etc.. ( as you all know)

So is there any way to implement something similar to this in my time input field where user can select time ( hour: min :AM/PM)

I am a newbie ( with my first website) and this is my first question here.. pls consider

thank you

Comment: What about just a normal `<select>`? One for the hour and one for the minute.

Comment: How about one of the dozen date/time/datetime selectors which are available?

Comment: use input field as text and apply datetime picker.

Comment: Try looking through the list of polyfill scripts available here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms

Comment: nice responses experts !!!                                             @j08691 i can use 3 selects in one field and when i submit i can get the time value? am i right?

Comment: I wish you hadn't closed the issue. I built this time input polyfill since I couldn't find any good ones anywhere: https://dan503.github.io/time-input-polyfill/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try jquery time picker, i always this one

http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html

If you want something very simple then try

http://keith-wood.name/timeEntry.html

this one is similar to `<input type="time">`

Comment: This is cool !! But I havent used jQuery yet ,, how can i start ?  I may have to download something ,, right??    thank you again